# Getting the following error Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to create a simple calculator and this is the code I have input.

```
<input type="button" value=" 1 " onClick="calculator.answer.value += '1'" />
```

The problem is that I am getting the above error.  Not sure what could be the problem.
Below is the error again.

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Comment: calculator.answer isn't how you call the element.

Comment: So how would you call the element?

Comment: What is `calculator`, where is it defined? [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you really have an object with property called answer that itself is an object with property called value (that is what your code looks like), then you need to wrap your `calculator.answer.value += '1'` in function and execute that function on click.

```js
const calculator = {
  answer: {
    value: 0
  }
};

function addOne() {
  calculator.answer.value += 1;
  console.log(calculator.answer.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value=" 1 " onClick="addOne()" />
```

Although you should move that `onClick` code to js file and replace it with `addEventListener` method so that you don't clutter your HTML with JavaScript.

```js
const calculator = {
  answer: {
    value: 0
  }
};

const btn = document.querySelector('input');
btn.addEventListener('click', addOne);

function addOne() {
  calculator.answer.value += 1;
  console.log(calculator.answer.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value=" 1 " />
```